# Como isso pode ser melhorado? (é só um joguinho)

Tags: c++, jogos, refatoração

Tentei fazer esse jogo baseado nos Cartões Magicos. Como estou aprendendo ainda, foi como eu consegui fazer. Gostaria de ver outras versões para saber como eu poderia ter feito e o que eu fiz de "errado".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
main()

{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    //Variavel
    int v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6;
    int resultado;
    char alternativa;
    //Group 1
    printf("Pense em um número entre 1 e 63.\n");
    system("pause");
    printf("O número está neste grupo?\n");
    printf("1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,\n");
    printf("35,37,39,41,43,45,47,49,51,53,55,57,59,61,63\n");
    printf("s!\n");
    printf("n!\n");
    scanf("%s", &alternativa);
    if (alternativa == 's') {
        v1 = 1;
    }
    else if (alternativa == 'n') {
        v1 = 0;
    }
    //Group 2
    printf("O número está neste grupo?\n");
    printf("2,3,6,7,10,11,14,15,18,19,22,23,26,27,30,31,34,\n");
    printf("35,38,39,42,43,46,47,50,51,54,55,58,59,62,63\n");
    printf("s!\n");
    printf("n!\n");
    scanf("%s", &alternativa);
    if (alternativa == 's') {
        v2 = 2;
    }
    else if (alternativa == 'n') {
        v2 = 0;
    }
    //Group 3
    printf("O número está neste grupo?\n");
    printf("4,5,6,7,12,13,14,15,20,21,22,23,28,29,30,31,\n");
    printf("37,38,39,44,45,46,47,52,53,54,55,60,61,62,63\n");
    printf("s!\n");
    printf("n!\n");
    scanf("%s", &alternativa);
    if (alternativa == 's') {
        v3 = 4;
    }
    else if (alternativa == 'n') {
        v3 = 0;
    }
    //Group 4
    printf("O número está neste grupo?\n");
    printf("8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,\n");
    printf("40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63\n");
    printf("s!\n");
    printf("n!\n");
    scanf("%s", &alternativa);
    if (alternativa == 's') {
        v4 = 8;
    }
    else if (alternativa == 'n') {
        v4 = 0;
    }
    //Group 5
    printf("O número está neste grupo?\n");
    printf("16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,\n");
    printf("48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63\n");
    printf("s!\n");
    printf("n!\n");
    scanf("%s", &alternativa);
    if (alternativa == 's') {
        v5 = 16;
    }
    else if (alternativa == 'n') {
        v5 = 0;
    }
    //Group 6
    printf("O número está neste grupo?\n");
    printf("32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,\n");
    printf("48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63\n");
    printf("s!\n");
    printf("n!\n");
    scanf("%s", &alternativa);
    if (alternativa == 's') {
        v6 = 32;
    }
    else if (alternativa == 'n') {
        v6 = 0;
    }
    //
    resultado = v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 + v5 + v6;
    printf("O número é:%d\n", resultado);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: vc pode começar usando a função "cout" ao invés de "printf", veja essa thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872543/printf-vs-cout-in-c

Comment: Você também pode utilizar `cin` que é o fluxo de entrada padrão do C++: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cin/. Também sugiro ler algumas [Boas Práticas em C++](https://github.com/kelvins/Boas-Praticas-Cplusplus), isso pode te ajudar a melhorar seu código.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 4):

Eu faria assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Calcula(char *sequencia1, char *sequencia2, int pontos) {
    printf("O número está neste grupo?\n");
    printf(sequencia1);
    printf(sequencia2);
    printf("s!\nn!\n");
    char alternativa;
    scanf("%c", &alternativa);
    return alternativa == 's' ? pontos : 0;
}
int main() {
    int soma = 0;
    printf("Pense em um número entre 1 e 63 e aperte <enter>.\n");
    char alternativa;
    scanf("%c", &alternativa);
    soma += Calcula("1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,\n", "35,37,39,41,43,45,47,49,51,53,55,57,59,61,63\n", 1);
    soma += Calcula("2,3,6,7,10,11,14,15,18,19,22,23,26,27,30,31,34,\n", "35,38,39,42,43,46,47,50,51,54,55,58,59,62,63\n", 2);
    soma += Calcula("4,5,6,7,12,13,14,15,20,21,22,23,28,29,30,31,\n", "37,38,39,44,45,46,47,52,53,54,55,60,61,62,63\n", 4);
    soma += Calcula("8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,\n", "40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63\n", 8);
    soma += Calcula("16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,\n", "48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63\n", 16);
    soma += Calcula("32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,\n", "48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63\n", 32);
    printf ("O número é:%d\n", soma);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ONm4gR). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pjcajmbr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/GuessNumber.c).

A pergunta tem *tag* C++, mas o código está todo em C, então fiz assim, e dentro do padrão normalmente aceito.

Retirei tudo o que não está sendo usado ou não era necessário. Incluindo os comentários que não diziam nada útil.

Organizei o código com um estilo mais padronizado, intuitivo e legível, até mesmo os espaços.

Eliminei variáveis desnecessárias.

Eliminei os `pause` que não costuma ser uma boa ideia.

Preferi eliminar a necessidade de dar <kbd>ENTER</kbd> aceitando um caractere.

A grande mudança foi fazer tudo o que era repetido estar em uma função parametrizada. O nome poderia ter sido melhor escolhido.

Nesta função simplifiquei algumas coisas, entre elas a eliminação do `if`.

Poderia ter criado uma condição para aceitar o `S` ou `N` maiúsculos.

Dá para fazer outras coisas cosméticas.

Se analisar com mais profundidade talvez essas sequencias possa ser calculadas e geradas na hora em vez de ser descrita explicitamente. O que provavelmente farei depois, já achei um padrão. Dá para chamar a função em um laço. Se tivesse o requisito que não pode usar função seria simples dentro deste laço.

Answer (score 1):

Uma possibilidade de optimização é utilizando arrays. Pode ser construído um array bidimensional com as series de números mostradas por pergunta, depois com um laço `for` percorre-se cada um dos elementos desse array e mostrasse à medida que se calcula o `resultado`.

```
#define PERGUNTAS 6 //definição da quantidade de perguntas existente para ser facil criar mais

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    //agora aqui o array de perguntas
    char* series[PERGUNTAS][50] = {
        {"1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,","35,37,39,41,43,45,47,49,51,53,55,57,59,61,63"},
        {"2,3,6,7,10,11,14,15,18,19,22,23,26,27,30,31,34,","35,38,39,42,43,46,47,50,51,54,55,58,59,62,63"},
        {"4,5,6,7,12,13,14,15,20,21,22,23,28,29,30,31,","37,38,39,44,45,46,47,52,53,54,55,60,61,62,63"},
        {"8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,","40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63"},
        {"16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,","48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63"},
        {"32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,","48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63"}
    };

    int resultado = 0, i, pontuacao = 1;
    char alternativa;
    printf("Pense em um número entre 1 e 63.\n");

    for (i = 0; i < PERGUNTAS; ++i){
        printf("O número está neste grupo?\n%s\n%s\ns!\nn!\n", series[i][0], series[i][1]);
        scanf("%s", &alternativa);
        if (alternativa == 's') resultado += pontuacao; //apenas aumenta resultado se for sim
        pontuacao *= 2; //pontuação para a próxima pergunta calculada aqui
    }

    printf("O número é:%d\n", resultado);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cada grupo de números pode ser calculado dinamicamente por meio de uma função (`obter_grupo()`), que por sua vez, pode ser chamada dentro de um laço, evitando assim a repetição desnecessária de código e a declaração de constantes cheias de números mágicos, vejamos:

```
#include <stdio.h>


void exibir_grupo( int grp[32] )
{
    int i = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < 32; i++ )
        printf( "%s%d", (i>0)?",":"", grp[i] );

    printf("\n");
}


void obter_grupo( int grp[32], int n )
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < 64; i++ )
        if( i & (1 << n) )
            grp[ j++ ] = i;
}


int main( void )
{
    int i = 0;
    int res = 0;
    char op = 0;
    int grp[32];

    printf("Pense em um número entre 1 e 63...\n");

    for( i = 0; i < 6; i++ )
    {
        obter_grupo( grp, i );

        printf("\nO numero esta neste grupo:\n");

        exibir_grupo( grp );

        printf("[S/N]? ");
        scanf( " %c", &op );

        if( op == 'S' || op == 's' )
            res += grp[0];
    }

    printf("\nO numero eh: %d\n", res );

    return 0;
}
```

Referência:
http://www.numericana.com/answer/magic.htm#binary